# Display message using php before starting file download

Tags: php, file-io, nginx, http-headers

I am using this PHP code to start a download but want to show "HTML" before/after initiating the download but the following code results in a blank page :

**Function to output html :**

```
function writeMsg($msg)
{
    echo "<html><body><h2>$msg</h2></body></html>";
}
```

**Called using :**

```
if(file_exists ($fullpath)) {
//Start Download
ob_start();
writeMsg('Download Started');
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fname\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Connection: close');
ob_end_flush();
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible because you set the header type to application/octet-stream which means that it is a binary file that must be opened using an application.

instead, you can display the text then redirect the user using HTML or Javascript

in HTML you can use the following

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_HERE; URL=DOWNLOAD_LINK_HERE">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Probably you would need a modal to show the loading text if not show inline text.

```
HTML MARK UP 
<a href="#" id="d1">Download Now</a>

// Jquery
$(function(){
 $('#d1').click(function(){

   $(this).text('Download Started...');

   setTimeout(function(){

        window.location.replace('http://domain.com/download.php');

   },2000);

   return false;

 })
});
```

Comment: One more thing, I am using X-Sendfile header to push files without revealing the original file location on disk to prevent direct downloading - so will this work with that ?

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done using javascript at the client side I am now using this : https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload

> jQuery File Download is a cross server platform compatible jQuery
>   plugin that allows for an Ajax-like file download experience that
>   isn't normally possible using the web.